# cordova facebookConnect - login refresh on samsung g s3

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have recently decided to test Cordava FacebookConnect (https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect).

I have managed to install on an Android project which works on the Android Virtual Device. But when I plugin my Samsung GS3, The device has a fit and just keeps refreshing the application.

My code is very basic:

```
var app = {

    initialize : function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },  

    onDeviceReady: function() {

        var facebookConnect = window.plugins.facebookConnect;

        console.log('ready');

        facebookConnect.login(
            { 
                permissions : ["email", "user_about_me"], 
                appId       : "3560694656564117"
            }, function(result) 
        {

            console.log("FacebookConnect.login:" + JSON.stringify(result));

            if( result.cancelled || result.error ) {

                console.log("FacebookConnect.login:failedWithError:" );

            }

        });

    }

};
```

What is weird is that the console logs "ready" every second which is not inside the facebookConnect callback. It as if I have previously logged in, revisited the app, the plugin verifies my credentials, the dialog closes and then it starts again! If I comment out the facebookConnect login method it just loads as normal, the console logs "ready" only the once.

Has anyone come across this before?

Regards

Comment: sorry to bump this but Iv'e tried everything..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you setup the native android app section in the facebook app dashboard. Especially the hash key section.

You should indicate whether the facebook callback got called or not.

You can always look in the logcat if there are fb errors that come out.

Comment: I believe I have correctly added the debug and apk hashes in the dashboard and the package and class names. I have recently downloaded candy crush app and I cant connect to facebook, which seems to behave in the same manor. Could this be related?